# Passing a lot of records from view to DB in MVC

Tags: sql, asp.net, asp.net-mvc

So I recently faced a question, as how to insert a lot of records (million in this case) from user input (in View) ultimately to DB in a MVC web application.
I gave 2 options:

1. We can pass the records in DataTable format and run a loop calling a method which in turn calls a procedure inserting into the table - Rejected since this will take a lot of time
2. We divide the data into a insert friendly string(s), and then pass it to a method which has a part of the query hardcoded and then append the string at the end, so something like 
   "Insert into Table (c1,c2) values" + string1 where string1 is "(1,1),(2,2)..." and in this way even if we cannot pass the whole input as a single string, the number of traversals of the loop would surely be reduced.

But none of these were accepted, so any idea what is the proper correct answer?

Answer (score 0):

According to my opinion, Loop is not a good practice to Insert bulk of data.
In this scenario you have to work with `Stored Procedures`. Store Procedures are the good for insertion of bulk of data.
In this case you will make the `Json` of your data & pass it to the procedures. In procedure you parse json and save it to the DB tables.
Hopefully, you understand it.